# Removing NULLs from a Pivot in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Any help that can be provided would be much appreciated.

I'm pivoting data from a view in sql server 2008.

The data in the view looks as follows:

```
Ticker  Acct       QTY
------ ------- ---------- 
AA05    SMBOND  5522000.0000
AA05    SMCORB  485000.0000
AB06    SMCORB  1777000.0000
AB06    SMBOND  191019.0000
AB07    SMBOND  557160.0000
AB07    SMCORB  10853000.0000
ABL11A  SMCORB  80000.0000
```

I'm running the following SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols 
  = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + ACCT_CD
           from vw_SLIB_FI_Rebal
           group by ACCT_CD
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')



set @query = 'SELECT TICKER,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select TICKER, 
                  ACCT_CD,
                  QTY_SOD
                from vw_SLIB_FI_Rebal
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(QTY_SOD)
                for ACCT_CD in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

and this is the result I get:

```
Ticker  SMBOND       SMCORB
------ ------- ---------- 
AA05    5522000.0000 485000.0000
AB06    191019.0000  1777000.0000
AB07    557160.0000  10853000.0000
ABL11A  NULL         80000.0000 '
```

I want to remove the NULL and make it a 0. Please help.

I will gradly provide any additional information if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall if it's possible to use the ISNULL function in the PIVOT part of the statement, but try this first:

```
pivot
(
    isnull(max(QTY_SOD), 0)
    for ...
)
```

If that doesn't work, you can always add the ISNULL function to each of the value columns. You will need a separate variable to hold the column headers, as you will still need your unchanged @cols variable in the IN-part of the PIVOT-statement:

```
select @colsHeader = STUFF((SELECT ', isnull(' + ACCT_CD + ', 0) AS ' + ACCT_CT
       from vw_SLIB_FI_Rebal
       group by ACCT_CD
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,''),
    @cols = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + ACCT_CD
       from vw_SLIB_FI_Rebal
       group by ACCT_CD
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately you can't use ISNULL in the PIVOT part of the statement. The 2nd SQL statement also doesn't work. I've tried to trouble shot with no luck... Please help

Comment: @Andrew I just realised that you need an additional variable for the column headers, and one for the IN-part of the pivot statement. I'm editing my answer now.

Comment: It works. Just a side not, my set @ query now looks as follows: